# Configuring apache on ipv6 no connection

Tags: apache, ipv6

**Solution**: It turns out ipv6 has got it's own firewall which I didn't know and it filtered out 80 and 443! Thanks so much Nicholas Pipitone!

I'm having difficulties to get apache to accept ipv6 connections (everything perfect on ipv4). Results from ready.chair6.net:

[image: Test result]

What I tested/tried:

- Disabling firewall doesn't change the result
- Getting apache to listen on all interfaces or specifically the ipv6 interface doesnt change the result
- Executing 'curl https://v6.ident.me/' correctly sends me back my ipv6 address
- Netstat tells me that both the ipv4 AND ipv6 address are listening for connections on 80 and 443

I'm really stuck here, what else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MX record error means it's having a problem getting the IP address from the DNS servers.

Solution: Try `dig +short AAAA $hostname` and `dig +short MX $hostname`, with `$hostname` being your URL. If you don't see an IPv6 IP in the terminal, then you don't have DNS fully setup. If you just recently setup  your URL, then wait a day for caches to be updated. If it's been a while, talk to who you bought the domain name from / who's responsible for making your URL point to your IP.

Note: MX is only for mail. If you don't want incoming mail / that's not what the problem is, then that test is testing something it doesn't have to test, and you can ignore it.

More possibilities: Is the hostname on line 4 the same as the host name on the second to last line? Try pinging that IPv6 address from line 4 on a different computer (Not on the same private network); what do you get?

If you get a response, try `nmap`ing the IPv6 on another computer to see if port 80 is open to the public.

-If the `nmap` fails then try checking your port forwarding settings if you're behind a NAT. If you're not behind the NAT then something might be blocking the request in-between their computer and your computer (Very unlikely); you can try telnet'ing to port 80 remotely and see if you're getting the requests - because then it's just an apache issue.

-If `nmap` succeeded, then what do you get? Send an HTTP request over command line from the another computer and see if you get a response.

If pinging doesn't work, then you're just not connected to the internet (o.O), idk how to help with that. If pinging the IPv6 works but pinging the URL doesn't, then `dig` must not be showing anything and it's the DNS as mentioned previously. If `dig` does show something in that case, then I'm lost.

Comment: I think I've exhausted every troubleshooting path. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much for your ideas. The dig command showed me the correct ipv6 address (i don't care about mail though). Nmap shows the ports are open, and I can connect perfectly fine to the website on a different computer outside the network (as shown in the test result image). It's just ipv6 not working :-/

Comment: @Franky I mean `nmap` on IPv6, if that's not what you did. All of my troubleshooting is with IPv6, so make sure you don't use IPv4 for any of it (Use the IP not the URL). I updated my answer

Comment: Oh sorry didn't get that! You know what, it says 80 and 443 are filtered!! Thank you so much!!